# Run .exe file from website doesn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, exe, execution

I can't figure out why - but it's not working!
In similar web application project, with same code - it's working well,
but from website - nothing!

I tried to use all kinds of possibilities from: System.Diagnostics.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath);
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(info);
```

and tried another way using:

```
Response.Redirect(FilePath); //with and without the extension
```

and i got that it worked for all other kinds of extensions (like pdf,html..) but never for the .exe!

One more thing: It's did make small window asked if i want to save or open current file, but the file name changed from **fileName.exe** to: **fileName_exe** 
(and then: which program you want to open the file with question...)

Thanks For Advance!

Comment: are you trying to run it on the client machine or your web server?

Comment: isn't it "unsafe" to allow browser to launch executable files on the client's computer? ... ^^ Probably a security issue ;)

Comment: "and i got that it worked for all other kinds of extensions (like pdf,html..) but never for the .exe" hopefully

Comment: Kinda dumb of a question (mine), but the exe is to be executed on server side, right?  Also, does it throw any kind of exceptions?

Comment: I'm trying to run it on the web server (I think..). How to be sure ?..  I tried change the filePath to both - "html//localhost/../file.exe" and to: "C://wwwroot/.../file.exe"

Comment: No exeptions. I don't think that what i trying to do is unsafe, i don't want run exe file inside the web, just that clicking on link in site that redirect to exe file somewhere will work. is it immpossible?..

Comment: To be more clear: I build index of links. Button click should let for the user open each one of the links in the index. Some of them pdf, other - exe. Is it impossible from website ??

Comment: Users can view pdf and other thing because browser supports viewing those. No browser will ever support running downloaded .exe. This is just acward and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass through browser. You should have some "backdoor" to execute it, and this backdoor should be process what have neccesary permissions.
As to solution of this problem you should create service what can accept requests to execute some file, and invoke it himselft. Then you just run service on you server and send your service this requests.

Comment: Can you explain hot to impliement this issue little bit more ?

Comment: This is proper explanation. You can find how to implement service in here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950421.aspx